# conversion from mysql to sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

i'm trying to convert a MySql data base to Sqlite but i'm facing a problem with the unique constraint of primary key, here is my MySql table code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `table01` (
  `idtable1` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `nom1` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable1` ASC),
  UNIQUE KEY `idtable1` (`idtable1` ASC)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and when i convert it using DBconvert for SQLite & MySql here is what i get:

```
CREATE TABLE table01 (
  idtable1  int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  nom1      varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idtable1
  ON table01
  (idtable1);
```

so when i read my data base, "using SQLite Maestro",  SQLite Maestro fail to recognize the primary key's unique contraint.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason may be SQLite's strange quirk: it is sensitive about the exact wording when it is about primary keys:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the
>   declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like
>   "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the
>   primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer
>   affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.